# Sort association rules by multiple columns in different order in r

Tags: r, sorting, arules, market-basket-analysis

I have transactional data and generated rules with `arules` package. I have difficulties sorting decreasing by `confidence`, increasing by `chi` and decreasing by `support`. How can I do this without converting to `dataframe`?

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter = list(support = 0.009, confidence = 0.25, minlen = 2))
quality(rules)$chi <- interestMeasure(rules, measure='chi', significance = TRUE, Groceries)
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
ordered.rules <- sort(sort(sort(rules, by ="confidence", decreasing = TRUE), by ="chi", decreasing = FALSE), by = "support", decreasing = TRUE)
inspect(ordered.rules[1:5])

library(dplyr)
rules %>% arrange(desc(rules@quality$confidence),rules@quality$chi, 
desc(rules@quality$support))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
ordered.rules2 <- sort(rules, 
  by = c(    "confidence", "chi",   "support"), 
  decreasing = c(TRUE,     FALSE,     TRUE))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! Why didn't I come up with it!?! -All the best,